# Use bash script with yt-download and ffmpeg to extract OR covert depending on format

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have a batch of files I uploaded to YouTube which I now wish to backup on my MacBook. When I download and extract the audio, I get either *.m4a or *. opus:

```
#!/bin/sh
ID="$1"

youtube-dl -f bestaudio -x -i --audio-format best -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s %(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list="$ID"
```

When the file extension is m4a, I need to leave it that way and perform no conversion, when the extension is opus, I need to convert it to m4a.

If I want to convert every file, I can do something like this:

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio -x -i --audio-format m4a -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s %(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list="$ID"
```

But then the conversion is performed no matter what.

How can I extract and only convert when the file extension is not m4a?

Comment: I assume you did not mean to ask a yes/no question. (If so, the answer is yes) Please update to ask a question to indicate the results you wish to achieve. Any code you have tried would be good to include as well.

Comment: @szatmary Thank you, I've done my best to make this a better question

Answer (score 0):

The m4a files that YouTube serves often contain incorrect/unusual headers and were therefore rewritten by youtube-dl. If all of your software can deal with these files, simply add the youtube-dl option

```
--fixup never
```

While you're at it, to download a YouTube playlist by ID, you can simply pass in the playlist ID to youtube-dl. Therefore,

```
youtube-dl (...) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list="$ID"
```

is better written as

```
youtube-dl (...) "$ID"
```

, which allows you to download Dailymotion, soundcloud and other playlists, including all the playlists in a YouTube profile (like `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/user/ThirstForScience/playlists` ).